# Skyrim lagging BAD on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wine

I recently installed Skyrim, and when i run the program, i have a bit of an issue.

The launcher loads great, and have had no problems with it. However, after i push play, and Skyrim loads, it starts to lag. The main menu is alright, with a slight lag, but i expected that.
When i start a new game, it takes at least 4 minutes to load to the opening cut-scene, and when it does, it is lagging horribly.

I let it play through to see what the outcome would be, and it got to the point where the audio was at the character creation, but the video was still on the carriage ride. Every bit of the game is laggy, even the start menu.

I dont know what could be causing this.

I have a Sony Vaio VGN-CS390JCR
4gb ram
500 gb hard drive
As for video card, i wasnt sure so this is what terminal says...

```
keegan@ThePOS:~$ sudo lshw -C video
[sudo] password for keegan: 
  *-display:0             
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:43 memory:d0000000-d03fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:60f0(size=8)
  *-display:1 UNCLAIMED
   description: Display controller
   product: Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2.1
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
   version: 07
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:d3400000-d34fffff
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it okay that you have 4 GB of RAM and a 500 GB of hard drive space, but for gaming these two parameters are not the main for running a game with a good framerate and no lag. The poor performance can be caused by the central processing unit (CPU) and the graphics card. Your graphics card is not good enough to run smoothly new games, because most of the integrated graphics cards by Intel are not designed for running games on high resolution and high settings. It has a 64-bit memory bus, low gpu and memory frequencies, etc.

You can try to turn off some graphics effects and low down some settings. And, of course, running a game under Linux may cause some lag, because the game is optimized for Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I used to play Skyrim all the time on this laptop on Windows, but it lagged when i switched over to Ubuntu. Maybe just the combonation of ubuntu and my graphics card make it worse.. I guess there isnt anything i can do about it then :P Ive tried turning off almost all of the graphics effects and set all setting the lowest they can go, and it still lags pretty bad.